# How to run a project in single docker container and run the installed dependencies of project in docker filesystem instead of using docker images?

Tags: mysql, django, docker, redis

I am new to docker I am noob and I have a full running application in docker consist of multiple containers responsible to run the project. I want to make the container image and gave it to the client but when I pushed my project to docker-hub it can only contain one container in the repository at a time. So, now I want to work with single container instead of using the multiple containers running MySQL and Redis as the dependencies of project. So, I installed redis and MySQL inside the docker file-system using bash of my container. But my project is not working without running my project I cannot start the redis and MySQL installed inside the container which is running on Debian Linux and when I run my project I can access the bash of my container and start the services but still my django app in the container is giving errors relevant to SQL. Can anyone tell me how to tackle this situation?

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to compile your multi-container application into a virtual machine, which is a very different setup.  You probably need to send the client the `docker-compose.yml` file as part of the setup to run the combined application, so they can run the multiple required containers themselves.

Comment: actually, I was working with multiple container project then I shifted to a single container currently I have just one container containing the source-code of my project rest of MySQL and Redis is installed in the debian on which my container is running now I want my project to use that instead of installing the images of MySQL and redis to again work in multi-container environment I want to prevent it